# Binding to dependencyproperty on a per object basis

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the following class schema

```
public Class Test : DependencyObject 
{
    private DependencyProperty _thickness = DependencyProperty.Register("Thickness", typeof(double), typeof(CounterDataStreamWrapper));
    public double Thickness
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (double)GetValue(this._thickness); 
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(this._thickness, value);
        }
    }


    ... Rest of the code
}
```

Essentially I have a collection of Test objects, and I want to bind the Thickness value for each one to its corresponding UI element. I am not too familiar with C# binding. When I try to create multiple objects, I am running into "DependencyProperty is already registered" issue. I am sure that I am just missing some key concept for binding to DependencyProperty.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are registering the Thickness DependencyProperty on the CounterDataStreamWrapper type and private per instance.

Make the DependencyProperty public static and register it for the class Test.

```
public static DependencyProperty Thickness = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Thickness", typeof(double), typeof(Test));
```

Comment: Actually, if it's static, how do multiple instances of Test have different values for Thickness?

Comment: You should name the static `ThicknessProperty`; it is an identifier, it is not the property itself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

Comment: @Jin that's how dependency properties work- registering the property is separate from storing the values.  The values are actually stored elsewhere and associated with an instance of `Test`

Answer (score 3):

It's supposed to be static. Like this:

```
private static DependencyProperty _thickness ...
```